# How to do the same or similar "Show windows side by side" I have on MSWindows on Linux with xfce-4.12

Tags: linux, windows, xfce

On MS Windows I have the option to "Show windows side by side" when Im with lots of browser windows and need organize:

[side by side on MS Windows example 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA6UJ.png)
[side by side on MS Windows example 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aktO6.png)
[the menu with the option on MS Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewDtU.png)

I cant find a way to do the same with Linux with xfce-4.12
Its not about tiling windows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ask Ubuntu post
[ubuntu 12.10 window tiling shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210231/xubuntu-12-10-window-tiling-shortcuts):

> By default, XFCE/Xubuntu tiling is a mouse only affair.
>
> However, you do have the ability to define your own keyboard
>   shortcuts:
>
> Using *settings manager --> window manager* you have the Tile Actions
>   as shown.
>
> In the picture I have defined two custom keyboard shortcuts
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to tile the current window to the top and
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to tile to the bottom.
>
> To define your own keyboard shortcut - double click in the *shortcut*
>   field next to the action.

[image]

You may also try
[QuickTile](http://ssokolow.com/quicktile/) :

> QuickTile is a simple utility, inspired by WinSplit Revolution for Windows, which adds window-tiling keybindings to your existing X11 window manager.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and effort to help me but I need automatically split screen by, at same time, resizing All windows to same size and arranging it on a mosaic, something like automatic resize and tile windows on his own place, like the pictures i put in question, the tile option you told just dock the active window on some border. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this being an old thread, let me mention **xpytile** which can tile windows and adds resizing of side-by-side windows, like "WinSplit Revolution" on MS-Windows.

https://github.com/jaywilkas/xpytile/